# jquery file upload: how to change the server upload file before submission

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have been reading the Jquery file upload wiki, but did not come across an example on how to modify the server upload folder on the fly.  Is there a working example on how to programmatic modify the php server upload directory?

Comment: It's a config directive.  Any particular reason why you need to do it programmatically?  I don't think you'll be able to, as your code doesn't even begin to execute until the file upload is finished.  You have to move the file later.

Comment: @Brad, The reason that I would like to achieve that is, I have multiple folders that I would like to upload the files to.  I created a combobox that lists directories.  I would like to select the specific directory then press upload.  I am thinking that I should pass form data then create a php script to move the specific file to the directory that has been chosen from the combobox. Do you have another idea that I can implement to achieve that goal?

Comment: I would not change the upload directory.  Just pass a variable along with the POST that tells your server side script where to place the file

Comment: @dottedquad, Yes, just move the file afterwards.  Who cares where the temporary file goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically off the JQuery Fileupload docs with a little more explanation by me.

```
//You should bind this to the same object you setup the fileupload on
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    // The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form
    var input = $('#inputWithVariable');

    //Add the new value as a variable called "folder" which will tell you which
    //directory they selected
    data.formData = {folder: input.val()};

    //Optional validation to make sure the input value exists
    if (!data.formData.example) {

     //If the value does not exist, return focus to the input 
     //or maybe select in your case and return false to prevent the upload
      input.focus();
      return false;
    }
});
```